# what is this driver = WebDriverManager.startDriver(browser, useragent) means?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

For this line of code in `Selenium`:

```
driver = WebDriverManager.startDriver(browser, useragent)
where
browser = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("browser");  and 
useragent = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter(useragent);
```

Does anybody know what this line is doing?  And where do we use `WebDriver Manager`?

Comment: What do the `WHERE` and `AND` clauses do in this code?  I have never seen that in the 10 years I have been writing automation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the "where", "and" stuff is just setting the parameters for that function, cucumber type coding.  So you would be pulling those parameters from some kind of context configuration.

It looks like WebDriverManager helps you set up the type of driver you want.  Making it easy to change from firefox, chrome, IE by hiding the configuration into that class.

Comment: hi @Chuck Brown : where and "and " both added by my self just for describe the sommands here .

Answer (score 0):

ITestContext is interface in TestNG which helps here, to get current Test which is under execution and fetching variables provided for that test. If i want to say in Java prospective, lets say you provided variable 'browser' with value as 'chrome' in testng.xml file for this test. This peace of code

```
  browser = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("browser");
```

get that variable value 'chrome' and assigning this to 'browser' variable in this class.

Regarding WebDriverManager, i am not yet used but for code provide it looks like peace of code or library which helps you start driver. To start the driver you are passing which driver need to start like chrome, firefox etc.. For example as here browser value is chrome, so its instantiate ChromeDriver nothing but opens chrome browser and continues execution. I hope you need to use this code to start the driver in normally as replacement of driver=new soandsodriver();

Thank You,
Murali